# App crashing due to memory warning

Tags: ios, uiimageview

I am working on one photographic app in that I am adding 10 effects to one image. I am using some libraries for this. After  sometime app is crashing . Its showing memory warning. I am using image after compression but still also app is crashing . Can any one tell me how to solve this memory warning . I am using this following code for image compression

```
-(UIImage *)resizeImage:(UIImage *)image {
int w = image.size.width;
int h = image.size.height; 

CGImageRef imageRef = [image CGImage];

int width, height;

int destWidth = 640;
int destHeight = 480;
if(w > h){
    width = destWidth;
    height = h*destWidth/w;
} else {
    height = destHeight;
    width = w*destHeight/h;
}

CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();

CGContextRef bitmap;
bitmap = CGBitmapContextCreate(NULL, width, height, 8, 4 * width, colorSpace, kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst);

if (image.imageOrientation == UIImageOrientationLeft) {
    CGContextRotateCTM (bitmap, M_PI/2);
    CGContextTranslateCTM (bitmap, 0, -height);

} else if (image.imageOrientation == UIImageOrientationRight) {
    CGContextRotateCTM (bitmap, -M_PI/2);
    CGContextTranslateCTM (bitmap, -width, 0);

} else if (image.imageOrientation == UIImageOrientationUp) {

} else if (image.imageOrientation == UIImageOrientationDown) {
    CGContextTranslateCTM (bitmap, width,height);
    CGContextRotateCTM (bitmap, -M_PI);

}

CGContextDrawImage(bitmap, CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height), imageRef);
CGImageRef ref = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(bitmap);
UIImage *result = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:ref];

CGContextRelease(bitmap);
CGImageRelease(ref);

return result;  
}
```

and  I am using that GPUImage library and  I have added GPUImageView for displaying image.
Please help me if someone has any idea.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The above code is just for resizing an image. Where are you getting these images from? How many do you have in memory at once? What does GPUImage have to do with this? You're going to need to provide a lot more information for us to even begin to help you here.

Comment: also: **Instruments** (start here: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#technotes/tn2151/_index.html)

Answer (score 1):

You need to release `colorspace`:

```
CGColorSpaceRelease(colorspace);
```

This may be a reason of leak, but if you call `resizeImage` many times then it can be the reason of crashes

Comment: It may be a leak, but I doubt color space objects take much memory--and in fact my be singleton objects for the common color spaces behind the scenes.